# postfix incoming queue not deletable files

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

My postfix incoming folder at */var/spool/postfix/incoming* (within chroot) on a debian squeeze instance is filled with a bunch of stange files that are not removable, stat'able, chmod'able or whatsoever:

```
drwx------  2 postfix root     4096 Nov 19 16:18 .
??????????  ? ?       ?           ?            ? 019E310000B9
??????????  ? ?       ?           ?            ? 0775C1000081
??????????  ? ?       ?           ?            ? 0874F1000082
??????????  ? ?       ?           ?            ? 180E41000083
[...]

$ file 019E310000B8
019E310000B8: ERROR: cannot open `019E310000B8' (Invalid argument)

$ cat 019E310000B8
cat: 019E310000B8: Invalid argument

$ rm 019E310000B8
rm: cannot remove `019E310000B8': Invalid argument
```

Additionally, my mail.log shows entries like the following for the files mentioned:

```
Nov 19 16:22:20 mail postfix/qmgr[1506]: warning: incoming/019E310000B8: Invalid argument
Nov 19 16:22:28 mail postfix/showq[1585]: warning: incoming/019E310000B8: Invalid argument
```

Does anyone have a hint for me what could be wrong? I am a bit helpless...

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a crash of a hard drive or a system crash or kernel panic ? I think your file system is corrupted, but you should see some logs concerning the problem. Check your memory before doing a fsck !

The ACL can block you too, but I think you don't change them...